# How to combine two actions into one object

Tags: r

I recently just started with R a few weeks ago at the Uni. We were given a problem which we had to solve. However in this problem, I find that there are two answers that fit the question:

Verify that you created lo_heval correctly (incl. missing values). Store your verification in the object proof2.

So i find this is correct:

```
proof2 <- soep[1:100, c("heval", "lo_heval")]
```

But I think that this answer is also correct:

```
proof2 <- table(soep$heval, soep$lo_heval, useNA = "always")
```

Instead of having to decide for one answer, how do I combine them both into the object? I tried to use `&`, but I get an error. I may be using it wrong.

Prof. if you're seeing this, please don't fail me. I just can't decide between them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R `list`s can hold any arbitrary objects in them, so you could use

```
proof2 <- list(
  soep[1:100, c("heval", "lo_heval")],
  table(soep$heval, soep$lo_heval, useNA = "always")
)
```

However, to my mind 100 rows of two columns isn't proof - it's an exercise to look through those and verify things are right. (And what about the rows past 100? It's a decent spot check, but if there are more rows in the data it is more *strong evidence* than *proof*.) The `table` approach, on the other hand, seems succinct and effective.